# How to make two level lists

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm making a simple app where I'll have two level lists. I've created the first level list with `ListView` but I'm not sure how to go about creating second level list.

Example:

First level list is:

```
 Fruits
 Cookies
```

When Fruits is clicked then the list below is shown:

```
 Bananans
 Grapes
 Apples
```

When cookies is clicked then the list below is shown:

```
 Oreo's 
 Choc Chip
```

Code for first level list:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt;
    List<Map<String, String>> list1 = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initList();
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, list1, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"list1"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
    }

    private void initList() {
        // We populate the planets
        list1.add(creatList1("list1", "Fruits"));
        list1.add(creatList1("list1", "Cookies"));
    }

    private HashMap<String, String> creatList1(String key, String name) {
        HashMap<String, String> list = new HashMap<String, String>();
        list.put(key, name);
        return list;
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if you don't want to use ExpandableListView than which type of functionality you want?

Comment: i just want list1 on one screen then when an item is clicked i want to show list2 on second screen

Comment: u can use viewPager or viewFlipper for this...you have to send list to one screen to other.

Answer (score 0):

Check out for [ExpandableListView](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/). I suits to your need.